# Returning the description field of a dropdown list to the model after a Post

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In my model, I have a field which is of type Category.

```
...
public Category Category { get; set; }
...
```

The Category class is similar to this:

```
public class Category 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the HtmlHelper for DropDownLists in my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category.Id, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Description"))
```

When I **Post** my form, the Category field on the model is set to an instance of a Category object which has it's Id value correctly set.

The description field is left null. I understand that the whole class is not serialized and passed to the client, and I wouldn't necessarily want that for complex classes. Also for a lot of cases I can simply use the Id to find the correct element.

Is it possible tough to have the description field also returned to the model so I can then use this field?

If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible tough to have the description field also returned to
>   the model so I can then use this field?

The only way to do this is to use javascript. There's nothing in HTML that allows you to send the text of an `<option>` tag. Only the value is sent to the server.

So basically you will have to subscribe to the `onchange` event of this dropdown list, retrieve the text of the selected element and stuff it into a hidden field with a proper name.

So, hidden field with a proper name within the form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Category.Description, new { id = "description" })
```

and then give an id to your dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.Category.Id, 
    new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Description"),
    new { id = "category" }
)
```

and finally subscribe:

```
$('#category').change(function() {
    var description = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $('#description').val(description);
});
```

But if you want me to be totally honest with you: please don't do this and simply retrieve the description from your underlying backend using the selected id that is sent to your server.

Comment: Ok, I'm not surprised. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Do you know if the Asp.net dropdown list control does this by default?

Comment: I am not sure. It's been ages since I have touched to classic ASP.NET WebForms. It's possible that it actually sends the text along with the selected value. I wouldn't be surprised - with all the ViewState crap that gets posted to the server. It shouldn't be very tough to verify it.